# ASP.NET async action return types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with some controller, views and actions and so on.

I have heard that I should be able to make my controller actions async without any problems, but I'm really struggling with how to return views in that case.

I have this action called `UpdateUser()` which is async, and has some functions that I want to have the `await` keyword (more are to be added). After doing these operations, I need to return to a view, like in most controller action:

```
public async Task Updateuser()
{
    ApplicationUser usr =  await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

    string  name = usr.UserName;
    string email = usr.Email;
    string UserEmail = name + email;
    string hash = "";

    using (var sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed())
    {
        // Convert the string to a byte array first, to be processed
        byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UserEmail);
        byte[] hashBytes = sha.ComputeHash(textBytes);

        // Convert back to a string, removing the '-' that BitConverter adds
        hash = BitConverter
            .ToString(hashBytes)
            .Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
    }

    return View();
}
```

So at the line where it says `return View();` my IDE is angry about the return type, because the return type needs to be a `Task.

So how do I return my view, using async methods?

Comment: I suspect the method signature should be `Task<ActionResult>` (or `Task<IActionResult>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use IActionResult to return the view from MVC controller's action. Your method should like the following with the async task:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Updateuser()
{    
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Please give upvote if it solves your problem.